# Android MediaPlayer read from an InputStream

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I need to implement a video DASH client for Android.

At this time I haven't find any solution except write the `InputStream` in a temp file and then read the file. Of course this solution is not efficient at all. I thought to use an `OutputStream` to use its `FileDescriptor` as the data source. But I'm not able to use a valid `FileDescriptor` without creating an existing file...

Because of the DASH protocol, the client has the charge of getting all the (little) segments, so I really need to find a way to read the media directly from the memory. Maybe the only solution is to use the JNI but I don't really know how.

To resume I'm open to every suggestions. The only constraints are :

- At first I have an `InputStream`
- Here it can be any intermediate operations but the more efficient as possible
- Get a valid input to feed a `MediaPlayer`

That seems pretty basic but I can't found any way to achieve that. Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have this same problem I tried to solve it using PipedInputStream and PipedOutputStream, but they don't have a FileDescriptor to get and use on the MediaPlayer.setDataSource method. I also tried to create an URI form the PipedInputStream, but no sucess yet.

Comment: @Derzu Actually I spent a lot of time on this and finally i gave up... But let me known if you find a solution please.

Comment: I found a solution, but I'm still developing on it. Is to create a HTTP local server where the video data source is from an input stream. So the MediaPlayer reads from an http uri. Se this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257364/modifying-fileinputstream-for-mediaplayer-setdatasource/9428462

Comment: Hey Derzu Have you got any success I am working on same problem I think we can solve it by working together.

Answer (score 0):

Derzu is correct that a local proxy can do this. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701249/getting-access-to-media-player-cache). Feel free to ask any questions.