# How to play a video from Byte array?

Tags: java, android, encryption, arrays

I am working on an app which needs encryption of video files which is working quite well.But the method I am using to decrypt returns the video as in Byte array. So is there anyway that I can play the video using that array without creating a new file.

My method decryption:

```
  private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted) throws EncrypterException {
SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
try {
    final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);

    return cipher.doFinal(encrypted);

} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new EncrypterException(e);
}
}
```

Please help me I am stuck here ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How do you usually play video? You send `InputStrem` instance to player. 
So you `ByteArrayInputStream` that wraps your byte array and send it to the player.

Comment: @Navdroid: A ByteArrayInputStream is an InputStream.

Comment: But I want to use it VideoView ..How can I use it without creating a new file

Comment: Did you get a solution for this? I'm also trying to play a video that I've loaded from a local DB, do I really have to save it to 'disk' to allow me to play it back? The VideoView control only allows you to set the Uri/File for playback. Maybe there's another way of playing videos without using the VideoView?

Comment: how is this the answer to the question?

Comment: Did you find the solution? Navdroid

Comment: This is not a solution!

Comment: @Berkay, you are welcome to provide your own solution.

Answer (score 6):

After lots of search, this answer could be a sum up. All credits should go the solution owners.

Since `VideoView` only accept URL or File, we have two solution;

**Solution 1;** Create temp File with stream and provide that file to videoView.

Ref; https://stackoverflow.com/a/21549067/1847645

**Solution 2;** Create media server on Android Local System and provide stream to media server where videoView is directed to the localhost for streaming.

Ref; https://stackoverflow.com/a/9096241/1847645

Other Ref;
Which is very useful, thanks to libeasy; https://stackoverflow.com/a/15668803/1847645

Answer (score -2):

You should not feed VideoView with a static file but with a stream. How to produce this stream?
Refer to [Android Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html). The simplest may be a local http server. LocalSingleHttpServer is an example of a library component implementing this kind of solution.