# Playing encrypted video files using VideoView

Tags: android, android-videoview

Does android native "VideoView" video rendering widget plays encrypted video files?
And if yes then how to play it and what all the APIs.
I have gone through this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html) i don't find anything related playing encrypted video.

Is it that i need to decrypt my video and then pass it to VideoView?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

VideoView can't play an encrypted video, you have to decrypt it yourself. There are roughly two ways:

1. generate a temporary clear file from the encrypted one, but this has some inconveniences: a delay before to start the playing and an exposure of the contents in clear.
2. use a streaming scheme, with a local http server.

[libmedia](http://libeasy.alwaysdata.net/) is a library developed to precisely address this feature.

Something like:

```
mServer = new LocalSingleHttpServer();
mServer.setCipher(myGetCipher());
mServer.start();
path = mServer.getURL(path);
mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
mVideoView.start();
```