# Play bytearray in VideoView

Tags: android, encryption, android-videoview

I need to download encrypted video, decrypt it and play in VideoView. But problem is that VideoView needs a path to file. 
How is it possible to play decrypted video so it's only visible via my app.

When I decrypt I have `byte[] outputBytes`
I was thinking about two solutions...
1. Is it possible to make file in memory that will be deleted every time user is not in the app?
2. Or maybe to extend VideoView class and override methods so they work with byte array

Comment: you may have to write those bytes back to a video file like .mp4 or something and delete it onStop/onDestroy.. but not sure

Comment: That's what I was thinking. What if app crashes or something like that, that will skip  going into onDestroy/Stop?

Comment: Nikola, check this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9495366/how-to-play-a-video-from-byte-array

Comment: I saw that answer but couldn't find the way to pass InputStream to VideoView... Do you have code sample for that? Also I was searching in documentation for VideoView and couldn't find InputStream.

Comment: here you go, https://stackoverflow.com/a/21549067/6142219

Comment: Thanks a lot. Should I delete this question?

Comment: It is fine!. :D

Comment: you should post answer yourself if you got one